# Ionic modules problem after I tried to upgrade my Angular CLI ,Ionic and cordova

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I tried to upgrade my Angular CLI , Ionic and Cordova version , Now I cant run my ionic serve any more, when I try to unintall versions and install olders I keep get an error but a little bit different.

now I get :

```
Module '"C:/Users/mylaptop30/Desktop/ArbesTech-Projects/Andrian/InstantDealNew/node_modules/firebase/index"' has no exported member 'functions'.
```

My versions are:  `Ionic@3.9.2` ,`Cordova 8.1.2(Cordova-lib@8.1.1)` `Angular 6.4.1.`

before I tried to play with my firebase version i got :

```
cannot find module firebase/app
```

and when I tried to upgrade my Angular CLI  i got :

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'
```

I searched all over the internet the solution for each error but when I fix one another one is coming.
Please Help me!!!

This is my `Package.json` file:

```
  "name": "Instant Deal",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/contacts": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/media-capture": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "android": "0.0.8",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-accountkit": "^1.4.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-contacts": "^2.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.10.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^5.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-media-capture": "^1.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.1",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^4.8.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-contacts": {
        "CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "es6-promise-plugin": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
```

and my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{

  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@angular/*": ["node_modules/@angular/*"]
    },

    "baseUrl": "src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },

  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",

  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/__tests__/*.ts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your node_modules folder, and reinstall them to see if the error goes away.

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Your errors are kind of all over the place, so it's hard to pin down what all is causing it. I'm going to assume it's a number of different issues that are causing this, and not one localized issue.

Comment: Might be an issue with you using Angular 6.x.x. Try downgrading to Angular 5.x.x

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `npm rebuild` on your folder project to rebuild your addons